# How can I sort the outputted array into groups

Tags: php, sorting

My outputted array list is showing this;
[image]

I want to make it sort like:

```
Imran Omer
Imran Omer
sumair
sumair
sumair
sumair
sumair
wrewr
wrewr
wrewr
wrewr
wrewr
```

How can I sort it like this?

This is the code I am using;

```
if (!in_array($a['sid'],$leave_sids))
                {
                    $struck_off_list_bit .= '
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$a['sid'].'</td>
                            <td><a href="school_id.php?action=preview_id_card&sid='.$a['sid'].'">'.$a['student_name'].'</a></td>
                            <td>'.$date.'</td>
                            <td>'.$student_class.'</td>
                            <td style="background: #'.$bg_color.'">'.$leave_submitted.'</td>
                        </tr>
                    ';
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another option

```
function array_sort($arr, $key, $type = 'asc')
{
    $keys = $new_array = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $keys[$k] = $v[$key];
    }

    if ($type == 'asc') {
        asort($keys);
    } else {
        arsort($keys);
    }

    reset($keys);

    foreach ($keys as $k => $v) {
        $new_array[$k] = $arr[$k];
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

usage  `array_sort($a,'student_name')`

Comment: Thank you very much. You're help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for `usort()`.

First define a function such as

```
function sortByStudent($a, $b) {
    return $a['student_name'] - $b['student_name'];
}
```

Then, call it on your `$a` array:

```
usort($a, 'sortByStudent');
```

[PHP documentation for usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: Thank you very much. You're help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use array_multisort() function, your code should be like this code:

```
<?php
$students = array(
    array('sid' => '38', 'student_name' => 'wrewr'),
    array('sid' => '2', 'student_name' => 'Imran Omer'),
    array('sid' => '36', 'student_name' => 'sumair'),
    array('sid' => '2', 'student_name' => 'Imran Omer'),
    array('sid' => '36', 'student_name' => 'sumair'),
    array('sid' => '38', 'student_name' => 'wrewr'),
    array('sid' => '36', 'student_name' => 'sumair'),
);
$new_array = array();
foreach ($students as $key => $row) {
    $new_array[$key] = $row['student_name'];
}
array_multisort($new_array, SORT_ASC, $students);

print_r($students);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You're help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` clause in your query. It will automatically group all the results

Comment: Sorry but I am not using an sql query grouping. Anyway, thanks for help